# Firefox Extension Security Policies

Tags: security, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm searching for the security policies that Mozilla Firefox is applying for the extensions. Most of what I've read includes sandbox review system however I also read it not followed any more.

Can you please tell me what are the security polices that are 'currently' applied for the extensions?

Additionally, is there a security model for firefox?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the guidelines used by AMO Reviewers when revewing an addon - https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Reviewers/Guide/Reviewing

Comment: So they have canceled same origin policy and signing too?

Comment: @user4326614 I dont understand your question, can you please rephrase it.

Comment: There are two polices used previously before making the extension go public or in AMO there are three polices I know about. Sandbox policy, same-origin policy and signing policy.